# Are there any tensorflow optimizers which do not require gradient information?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to optimize a function for which no gradient information is available.

I was looking for an optimizer which does that but I cannot find one. Do they not exist?

Since there are several ways of estimating a gradient I expect that they do.

Comment: I don't think this exist. However, if you can implement a way to estimate gradients, you could call [`apply_gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#apply_gradients) with your own estimations.

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for the hint with apply_gradients. I might very well have to go down this route.

Comment: Also I don't know what is your use case but if you have just one particular operation (or group of operations) in your graph for which you cannot compute the gradient, you can do your estimation with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient) and everything else will work just fine. Well actually you can use that for your whole model if you want too.

Comment: You can try GA's :D but you wouldn't need tensorflow then.

Comment: @Lau What's a GA?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm Here is a link ;)